# Creating NSMutableDictionary with custom object as key is crashing in ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have property declaration in header file

```
@property (nonatomic,copy)CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER  *checkmaterial;
```

and implementation like this is .m file

```
NSMutableDictionary *headerdictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<self.delegate.replenishAddedmaterials.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *key = [self.delegate.replenishAddedmaterials.allKeys objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *materialarray = [self.delegate.replenishAddedmaterials objectForKey:key];

        //material array will hold
        // 1. material objects at index 0
        // 2. vendor objects at index 1
        // 3. Purchase organization objects at index 2

        MATERIAL_ITEM *material = [materialarray objectAtIndex:0];

        self.checkmaterial =[[CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER alloc] init];

        [self.checkmaterial setMATERIAL_NO:[material getMATERIAL_NO]];
        [self.checkmaterial setMATERIAL_DESC:[material getMAT_DESC]];
        [self.checkmaterial setOPEN_PO:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        [self.checkmaterial setOPEN_PR:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

        //add the header objects into header array
        [headerdictionary setObject:[NSArray array] forKey:self.checkmaterial];
}
```

My object is crashing like this,

`-[CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x13f92890`

please give me some solution.Project is implemented in ARC.

Comment: Does the CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER class (a horrible name class name btw :-) implement the `NSCopying` protocol, as required for keys in a dictionary? If yes, how is `copyWithZone` implemented?

Comment: @MartinR yes CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER has parent class as NSObejct and it implements NSCopying protocol.it is implementing NSCopying

Comment: NSObject does not conform to NSCopying. Can you show the implementation of `copyWithZone` in your CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER class?

Comment: @MartinR what implementation you are asking for?? is it CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER"?it is a class interface CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER : DataStructure and interface DataStructure : NSObject <IDataStructure>
 and  protocol IDataStructure <NSObject, NSCopying>

Comment: except that i didn't understand the implementation,it is very huge

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using copy instead of strong?

Comment: I just noticed that `self.checkmaterial` is used as a *key* in a dictionary, so there *might* be a problem. - Did you try to run with "Enable Zombie Objects" to locate the problem?

Comment: actually if i give retain as property it will crash with -[CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x13f92890.please

Comment: If i give strong for the property also it will crash with the message  -[CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1151f4a0

Comment: How did you assign the value of self.delegate.replenishAddedmaterials?

Comment: [delegate.replenishAddedmaterials setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:self.materialItem, nil] forKey:self.materialItem.getLid];
    [[delegate.replenishAddedmaterials objectForKey:self.materialItem.getLid] addObject:self.vendorHeader];
    [[delegate.replenishAddedmaterials  objectForKey:self.materialItem.getLid] addObject:self.purchasingorg];

Comment: How about your implementation of CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER class? Maybe there is something wrong inside this class. (And also, I agree with @MartinR, it is a horrible class name.)

Comment: If i do mutablecopy i am getting this message *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CHECK_MATERIAL_HEADER mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12ba26a0'

Comment: @yoninja - will class name is the cause for this crash:( .i don't think my big brother.It is wrecked my head.Dictionary taking custom objects as key is a big overhead in my projects.I want to learn how to copy object to dictionary

Comment: The class name is not the problem. It's just that it is off the convention. Anyway, do you really need to use custom objects as keys to theses dictionary objects? In your code above, we can't really pinpoint the problem. Things are happening with the objects before that method. Somebody has already hinted you to check the zombie objects. You should start with that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40688/discussion-between-narasimhaiah-kolli-and-yoninja)